# Options for adding a ChromeCast Button to existing app

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-api, android-fragmentactivity, chromecast

According to Google Cast Developer Guide, there are three ways to add a cast button,

1. Use the MediaRouterActionProvider - the easiest and recommended way of adding a Cast button. The MediaRouter will handle the entire lifecycle of the button including the visibility of the button when devices are discovered. You need to use the appcompat ActionBar and extend ActionBarActivity for your Activities.
2. Use the MediaRouteButton. You need to extend FragmentActivity for your Activities. Your app is responsible for managing the visibility of the Cast button based on the MediaRouter device discovery event callbacks.
3. Use a custom button.

So my question is, why do we need to extend either the ActionCompatActivity or the FragmentActivity in order to use the cast button provided by Google? Which part of the provided MediaRouterButton/MediaRouterActionProvider  depends on functionality of FragmentActivity/ActionCompatActivity? If my view extends neither of them, is there a workaround that would avoid creating a custom button?

Thanks.

Comment: `MediaRouterActionProvider` definitely requires `appcompat-v7`. I am not certain about `MediaRouteButton`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes. I'm asking the reason for such a requirement. Thanks

Comment: "I'm asking the reason for such a requirement" -- um, because that's how they wrote it. The backported action bar has a backport of action providers. Rather than write two `MediaRouteActionProvider` implementations, they chose to write one, and elected to use the action bar backport for that. I used to maintain a cross-port of `MediaRouteActionProvider` to use the native action bar, but that got too complicated.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see... Thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare I found out about your previous project on github. https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-mediarouter Could you explain why it's no longer practical to do the workaround you did? Could we still use your previous project then? Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Could you explain why it's no longer practical to do the workaround you did?" -- for me, at least, it was too much work to try to tease out all the `appcompat-v7` references. "Could we still use your previous project then?" -- it's open source. I cannot guarantee that it will work over the long haul. AFAIK, it still works now.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks so much for the response. So essentially, we're able to implement a cast button without having to extend the ActionBarActivity/ActionCompatActivity/FragmentActivity classes if I'm understanding correctly?

Comment: You are able to implement a `MediaRouteActionProvider` without having `appcompat-v7` as a dependency, which includes not needing to inherit from `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks so much for the project. Would it be possible for us to add a button to a view that extends a linear layout instead of an activity? If not, do you know what it would take for that to work? Thanks a lot..

Comment: You are welcome to play with `MediaRouteButton`. I have never used it directly personally.